# Failed to create new java File for path /storage/emulated/0/

Tags: nativescript

I'm tying to download a file to the folder on my external storage. 
So, initially there will be no folder & hence,
I need to create a folder if its not there and save my file in it.

```
try {
                console.log('Download Started');
                var directory = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
                var file = fs.path.join(directory, "/myfolder/" + this.pdf_url.split("/").pop());
                var folder = fs.Folder.fromPath(file).toString();
                var url = this.pdf_url;

                httpModule.getFile(url, file).then(function(r) {
                    console.log(r);
                }, function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("--error");
                console.log(error);
            }
```

Thats all, I'm getting this as **OUTPUT**

```
JS: Download Started
JS: --error
JS: Failed to create new java File for path /storage/emulated/0/akavya/2014.pdf
```

This is my `Manifest` file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**Update**
i followed this link and on ns preview app its working but not on my app.
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=w1YmMo&v=2&_ga=2.97108767.1865896142.1577943252-149906011.1576233431

Comment: Did you acquire the permissions at run time? You should use nativescript-permissions plugin to capture read / write external storage permission at run time.

Comment: @Manoj i used that plugin and pasted the code in app.js for write permission. and still I'm getting `Error: Cannot save file with path: /storage/emulated/0/test_folder.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced Similar issue, and i solved it by

```
const documents = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.documents();
                documents._path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                const folder = documents.getFolder('abcde');
                var file = fileSystemModule.path.join(folder._path, this.pdf_url.split("/").pop());
                var url = this.pdf_url;

                console.log("---folder");
                console.log(folder);
                console.log(file);
                console.log(url);
```